Writing one column over another
Let me start with MWE:
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(A&\triangle B)^C=((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))^C  &\mbox{by definition of symmetric difference}\\&=
( (A\cap B^C)\cup( B\cap A^C ) )^C  &\mbox{by definition of set difference}\\&=
(A\cap B^C)^C\cap ( B\cap A^C )^C   &\mbox{by De Morgan's laws}\\&=
(A^C\cup B)\cap (B^C\cup A)  &\mbox{by De Morgan's laws}\\&=
(A^C\cap B^C)\cup (A^C\cap A)\cup (B\cap B^C)\cup (B\cap A)   &\mbox{by Distributive property}\\&=
(A^C\cap B^C)\cup \mbox{\O}\cup\mbox{\O}\cup (B\cap A)  &\mbox{by Complement}\\&=
(A^C\cap B^C)\cup (B\cap A)   &\mbox{by Identity}\\&=
(A^C\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A^C)  &\mbox{by definition of set difference}\\&=
A^C\triangle B  &\mbox{by definition of symmetric difference.}%\tag*{$\blacklozenge$}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}

I like the layout except that it is too wide for the size of the page. I would love to shift the whole second column (one with explanations) to the left and keep it flushed to the right. I tried adding negative spaces with \kern-1em but it appears that TeX is set not to allow, what it sees as writing second column over the first. Is there a way to trick TeX to do it?

Can you please add a screenshot, and perhaps a sketch of your desired result, to your question? Thank you

The overfull \hbox is caused by the fifth line of the equation and the long annotation "by definition of symmetric difference".
One quick remedy is to issue \mkern in the fifth line:
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(A&\triangle B)^C=((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))^C &\mbox{by definition of symmetric difference}\\
& =( (A\cap B^C)\cup( B\cap A^C ) )^C  &\mbox{by definition of set difference}\\
& =(A\cap B^C)^C\cap ( B\cap A^C )^C   &\mbox{by De Morgan's laws}\\
& =(A^C\cup B)\cap (B^C\cup A)  &\mbox{by De Morgan's laws}\\
& =(A^C\cap B^C)\cup (A^C\cap A)\cup (B\cap B^C)\cup (B\cap A)\mkern-80mu   &\mbox{by Distributive property}\\
& =(A^C\cap B^C)\cup \mbox{\O}\cup\mbox{\O}\cup (B\cap A)  &\mbox{by Complement}\\
& =(A^C\cap B^C)\cup (B\cap A)   &\mbox{by Identity}\\&=
(A^C\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A^C)  &\mbox{by definition of set difference}\\
& =A^C\triangle B  &\mbox{by definition of symmetric difference.}%\tag*{$\blacklozenge$}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}



Wow! This is crazy! I tried \mkern in the first few lines. Cool!

You may want to define a derivation environment that takes care of the details.
It's an equation* environment that opens a minipage where the baseline distance is a bit increased for readability; lines are split at & and the part at the left is typeset as math material, that on the right as text; space is filled in between so the formula is at the left (with an indentation after the first line, specified as a length in the optional argument (default 1em).
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\symdif}{\mathbin{\triangle}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{derivation}{O{1em}b}
 {
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}
  \linespread{1.2}\normalfont
  \petrovic_derivation:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \end{minipage}
  \end{equation*}
 }{}

\seq_new:N \l__petrovic_derivation_lines_seq
\seq_new:N \l__petrovic_derivation_step_seq
\tl_new:N \l__petrovic_derivation_firststep_tl
\tl_new:N \l__petrovic_derivation_indent_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \petrovic_derivation:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__petrovic_derivation_indent_tl { #1 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__petrovic_derivation_lines_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__petrovic_derivation_lines_seq \l__petrovic_derivation_firststep_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__petrovic_derivation_step_seq { & } \l__petrovic_derivation_firststep_tl
  \__petrovic_derivation_step_print:nn {} {0pt}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__petrovic_derivation_lines_seq \__petrovic_derivation_step:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__petrovic_derivation_step:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__petrovic_derivation_step_seq { & } { #1 }
  \__petrovic_derivation_step_print:nV { \\ }  \l__petrovic_derivation_indent_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__petrovic_derivation_step_print:nn
 {
  #1 \makebox[\displaywidth][s]
   {
    $\displaystyle \hspace{#2} \seq_item:Nn \l__petrovic_derivation_step_seq { 1 }$
    \hfill
    \seq_item:Nn \l__petrovic_derivation_step_seq { 2 }
   } 
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__petrovic_derivation_step_print:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{derivation}
(A\symdif B)^C=((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))^C 
  & by definition of symmetric difference \\
=( (A\cap B^C)\cup( B\cap A^C ) )^C
  & by definition of set difference \\
=(A\cap B^C)^C\cap ( B\cap A^C )^C
  & by De Morgan's laws \\
=(A^C\cup B)\cap (B^C\cup A)
  & by De Morgan's laws \\
=(A^C\cap B^C)\cup (A^C\cap A)\cup (B\cap B^C)\cup (B\cap A)
  & by Distributive property \\
=(A^C\cap B^C)\cup \emptyset\cup \emptyset \cup (B\cap A)
  & by Complement \\
=(A^C\cap B^C)\cup (B\cap A)
  & by Identity \\
=(A^C\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A^C)
  & by definition of set difference \\
=A^C\symdif B
  & by definition of symmetric difference.
\end{derivation}

\end{document}


Please, don't use \mbox{\O} for the empty set. If you really want that symbol (the Danish letter Ø), do it in the proper way:
\renewcommand{\emptyset}{\text{\normalfont\O}}


Sorry to waste everyone's time. I found a trick:
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&(A\triangle B)^C=((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))^C  \tag*{by definition of symmetric difference}\\&=
( (A\cap B^C)\cup( B\cap A^C ) )^C  \tag*{by definition of set difference}\\&=
(A\cap B^C)^C\cap ( B\cap A^C )^C   \tag*{by De Morgan's laws}\\&=
(A^C\cup B)\cap (B^C\cup A)  \tag*{by De Morgan's laws}\\&=
(A^C\cap B^C)\cup (A^C\cap A)\cup (B\cap B^C)\cup (B\cap A)   \tag*{by Distributive property}\\&=
(A^C\cap B^C)\cup \mbox{\O}\cup\mbox{\O}\cup (B\cap A)  \tag*{by Complement}\\&=
(A^C\cap B^C)\cup (B\cap A)   \tag*{by Identity}\\&=
(A^C\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A^C)  \tag*{by definition of set difference}\\&=
A^C\triangle B  \tag*{by definition of symmetric difference}
\end{align*}
\end{document}

Still, an interesting issue: how to force TeX to write one column on the top of another?
